# How to make a many to many relation join and get the first element in a constructor whit jpa criteria?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria

I have 3 Classes with two relationships OneToMany and ManyToMany as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Company {
    private Long id;
    private boolean enabled;
    private String tradename;
    //items...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "company")
    @OrderColumn(name = "address_index")
    private Collection<CompanyAddress> addresses;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "companies_activities", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", 
               referencedColumnName = "id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "activity_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @OrderColumn(name = "activity_index")
    private Collection<CodeActivity> activities;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class CompanyAddress {
    //items...
    private String address;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Company company;
}
```

and 3th class :

```
@Entity
public class CodeActivity {
    //items...
    private String code;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "activities")
    private Collection<Company> companies;
}
```

How to retrieve the elements indicated by a criteria constructor?
Here is the class with the constructor:

```
class CurrentCompany {
      //items...

      public CurrentCompany(long id, boolean enabled, String tradename, String address, String code) {
      }
}
```

And the repository:

How to join these 3 classes to reconstruct the result in the previous class, knowing that the attributes addresses and activities are content lists in a company, and the requested result is a single element (The first) each, there is Is there a possibility to recover a company with its main address and its primary activity code by a single instruction jpa criteria?

```
public CurrentCompany getCurrentCompany(final Long companyId) {
     CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
     CriteriaQuery<CurrentCompany> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(CurrentCompany.class);

     Root<Company> root = criteriaQuery.from(Company.class);
     Join<Company, CodeActivity> activities = root.join("activities", JoinType.INNER);
     Join<Company, CompanyAddress> addresses = root.join("addresses", JoinType.LEFT);

     List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
     predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("id"), companyId));

     criteriaQuery.multiselect(builder.construct(CurrentCompany.class, root.get("id"), root.get("enabled"), 
                     root.get("tradename"), addresses.get("address"), activities.get("code")));
     criteriaQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

     //Error encountered:
     //org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
     //org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:

     //What should I add in order for me to select the first address and activity element?

     return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getSingleResult();
}
```

Thank you for all response!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I have understood the question well, what you want is to bring you the first result of a query that will multiply by N entries and by M depending on the number of elements in the second table and the third table respectively?

If so, I would try the following:

```
 return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery)
      .setFirstResult(0) // set the first result, 0 based
      .setMaxResults(1)  // set the number of recors
      .getResultList();  // you can try getSingleResult() but I prefer to use this in case there are 0 records that do not contain an error
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it's nice. But it's not what I'm looking for! It's more like a mad join something like select .. where join is first.
To clarify, when jpa selects ManyToMany relationships execute 2 select queries to map the data. I searched if there is a way to do this with a single request, I think it is impossible! Sorry for my language, I have male with English ..

Comment: Currently I also think it is impossible. Do you use JPA 2.1? if so could you try an entity graph of type load

Comment: Yes I am using jpa 2.1.8 with hibernate 5.3.11, apparently it is not a problem. I only looked if there is a possibility to load an entity with its manyToMany relations with a single request? Because in this relationship, hibernate executes 2 SQL queries to retrieve the object, one for the entity itself and others for the list of items found in its @ManyToMany relationship. I think that even if we find a solution with criteria, we had to execute the 2nd request !! So we decided to leave the object to hibernate in this case  